# Can I use Heroku to host a web app on a path of my custom domain?

Tags: web-applications, heroku, dns, flask

I have a personal website currently hosted on Weebly and the domain was bought on NameCheap.  I'm creating a little flask web app that just displays a graph/table and I'm most likely going to use Heroku to deploy it.  Is there anyway that I can make the web app display whenever someone visits a specific path of my domain?

I guess I could just redirect to the url provided by heroku, but I would rather have it on my domain.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like ``http://yoursite.com/app`` or would you be okay with using a subdomain such as ``http://app.yoursite.com``?

Comment: Either would be fine as long as I can link to it and it has my domain name in the URL.  Does Heroku/NameCheap do this sort of thing?

Comment: Your domain provider should almost definitely provide DNS management, which will allow you to add an "A" DNS record. This will enable you to set up a subdomain like the second option I outlined. The answer Moritz provided below should offer more help in this, though.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Yes. There is an article explaining how to do this here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains . Basically, you need to add the custom domain to heroku (in the dashboard: settings -> domains) and reconfigure the DNS of the target domain so that it will resolve to your heroku app.